# Hide non-breaking spaces in org-mode, but show them in code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, characters

Default Emacs settings show [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) as a kind of underscore. This is very useful because these otherwise invisible characters would break code execution in many programming languages, and would be very hard to debug.

The setting, documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Display.html), can be changed with the variable `nobreak-char-display`. Org-mode also gives ways to [specify file local variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

What I would like to achieve, though, is hiding these non-breaking spaces (which are very usual in the French language) everywhere in my org-mode file **except in code blocks**, where I need them to be plainly visible.  To give an illustration, I want the non-breaking space before the interrogation point below hidden, but the other two visible.

Is there any way to achieve that?

[image: Non-breaking spaces inside and outside code blocks]

Answer (score 1):

You could add the non-breaking space as a new font-lock keyword to `python-mode`:

```
;; I'm defining a new face, though any face with underline should work
(defface my-nobreak-space
  '((t :inherit default :underline t))
  "My non-breaking space face.")

(font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode '(("\u00a0" . 'my-nobreak-space)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'(lambda () (setq-local nobreak-char-display nil)))
```

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

You'll need to add the keyword to each major-mode language you use in org.

Comment: Thank you for this idea! I tried setting up your solution. It works perfectly for Python, but for C/C++, I can't get it to work. I tried `(font-lock-add-keywords 'cc-mode '(("\u00a0" . 'my-nobreak-space)))`.
Also, can you explain why you need to define a face, if, quote, "any face with an underline should work"? Are there faces *without* underlines ?

Comment: Try `(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode '(("\u00a0" . 'my-nobreak-space)))`.  I didn't need to define a face, but it allows me more flexibility.  Most standard faces don't have the underline attribute set, and for those that do, themes/customization might turn if off. By defining my own face, the display of the character is less prone to unexpected changes.